# How to apply GoogleColab stronger CPU and more RAM?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, intel, google-colaboratory

I use GoogleColab to test data stuctures like chain-hashmap,probe-hashmap,AVL-tree,red-black-tree,splay-tree(written in Python),and I store very large dataset(key-value pairs) with these data stuctures to test some operation running time,its scale just like a small wikipedia,so run these python script will use very much memory(RAM),GoogleColab offers a approximately 12G RAM but not enough for me,these python scripts will use about 20-30G RAM,so when I run python program in GoogleColab,will often raise an exception that"your program run over 12G upper bound",and often restarts.On the other hand,I have some PythonScript to do some recursion algorithm,as is seen to all,recursion algorithm use CPU vety mush(as well as RAM),when I run these algorithm with 20000+ recursion,GoogleColab often fails to run and restart,I knew that GoogleColab uses two cores of Intel-XEON CPU,but how do I apply more cores of CPU from Google?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot upgrade the `GPU` and `CPU` but you can increase the `RAM` from `12 gb` to `25gb` just by crashing the session with just by any non ending while loop.

```
l=[]
while 1:
    l.append('nothing')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work in the free version, as @jeffhale mentioned bellow.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to request more CPU/RAM from Google Colaboratory at this point, sorry.

Comment: it is a pity,but I still feel Google Colaboratory cloud computation's power,cloud computation is much more powerful than local computation

Answer (score 3):

Google Colab Pro recently launched for $9.99 a month (Feb. 2020). Users in the US can get higher resource limits and more frequent access to better resources.

Q&A from the [signup page](https://colab.research.google.com/signup)  is below:

What kinds of GPUs are available in Colab Pro?

> With Colab Pro you get priority access to our fastest GPUs. For example, you may get access to T4 and P100 GPUs at times when non-subscribers get K80s. You also get priority access to TPUs. There are still usage limits in Colab Pro, though, and the types of GPUs and TPUs available in Colab Pro may vary over time.
>
> In the free version of Colab there is very limited access to faster GPUs, and usage limits are much lower than they are in Colab Pro.

How long can notebooks run in Colab Pro?

> With Colab Pro your notebooks can stay connected for up to 24 hours, and idle timeouts are relatively lenient. Durations are not guaranteed, though, and idle timeouts may sometimes vary.
> In the free version of Colab notebooks can run for at most 12 hours, and idle timeouts are much stricter than in Colab Pro.

How much memory is available in Colab Pro?

> With Colab Pro you get priority access to high-memory VMs. These VMs generally have double the memory of standard Colab VMs, and twice as many CPUs. You will be able to access a notebook setting to enable high-memory VMs once you are subscribed. Additionally, you may sometimes be automatically assigned a high-memory VM when Colab detects that you are likely to need it. Resources are not guaranteed, though, and there are usage limits for high memory VMs.
>
> In the free version of Colab the high-memory preference is not available, and users are rarely automatically assigned high memory VMs.

Answer (score 1):

For a paid, high-capability solution, you may want to try [Google Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) instead

Comment: I am a college sudent for a EE major bachelor with no job/work,sadly I have no income(money) to pay,

Comment: if I get a job,which means,I have income/salary,I am glad to pay fot GoogleColab,but the qustion is

Answer (score 0):

For a better CPU and RAM option use: TPU and High-RAM.
My results were: 51 GB RAM and 20-Core(2 threads each) Intel CPU.